# Is There An Equivalent to EnsureDebugId() for Non-Widget Elements in GWT?

Tags: gwt, selenium, automation

I'm currently writing automated tests for a GWT application using Selenium and Java. For page elements that are Widgets, this is relatively straightforward, given that unique IDs can be set using the ensureDebugIds() method.

However, some types on the pages I work with are not widgets, but other types, possibly container types (such as Cells or grid rows that are essential HTML tables). Is there a similar method to ensureDebugIds() for this? Or is there a way to create custom IDs for these elements that acts in a similar way *compatible* with ensureDebugId()?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to closely collaborate with you dev team to set Id's on any element which GWT does not handle in its ensureDebugId. Its straightforward to id as all UIObjects have setId api. If any HTML code is being is injected then ids need to be determined by a simple convention and set up for Selenese test case writing to be easier.